# Annotating common terminology/abbreviations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

Does the stackexchange engine allow for some shorthands to be used for more descriptive terminology so as to not alienate newcomers/anyone else not familiar with the jargon? Hover on the below:

*I don't mind my [3-bet](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/145/360) with a [TPTK](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/145/360) get beaten by a [VBFDTHOTR](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/q/110/360) because I have mad [EV](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/145/360)!*

Maybe something along automatic annotation for common abbreviations or otherwise having them highlighted and titled? Looking at what's allowed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/185254), I can see that there is no out-of-the box support for it except for link-style annotations above that take forever to type.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea... the site glossary could be an actual semantic map of word -> definition, with a list of abbreviations, and any abbreviations found in questions or answers could have an appropriate `abbr` tag automatically added.

We would run into some conflicts however - for instance, tag is a fine word that may be used in many contexts, while TAG is deserving of an `abbr` tag.